# Doesn't translate the page in Django

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation, i18next

settings.py:

```py
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('ru', 'Русский'),
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('orders/', include('orders.urls')),
    path('', include('products.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('basket/', include('baskets.urls')),
]

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    *urlpatterns,
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I also created `locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo` and used `{% trans "text" %}` tags.
But language is not changed. In console in my browser "locale changed ru" with source "content.js.:678"

I try to write

```
activate('en')
print("Current language:", get_language())
```

But nothing will change. I also switched urls from ru to en, but it did not help either.